# Match content of stringlist with a single string

Tags: delphi-7

I'm looking for an easy way to match the content of a stringlist (loaded from filter.txt) with a single string.

Let's say the string is 'bla bla bla random words dog cat mouse random words', and my content of the stringlist is:

- house building cabin
- dog cat mouse
- chair seat hammock

Since 'dog cat mouse' is in my stringlist I want to ShowMessage('Match found!')

Anyone got an easy example how to do that without the filter being case sensitive?
I don't need a match if the single string is for example 'dog.cat.mouse'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through the `TStringList` and use `AnsiContainsText` (case-insensitive) or `AnsiCompareStr` (case-sensitive). For instance, if `Str` is the string you want to search, and `SL` is the `TStringList`, you can use something like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Found: Boolean;
begin
  Found := False;
  for i := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
    if AnsiContainsText(Str, SL[i]) then
    begin
      Found := True;
      Break;
    end;
  if Found then
    // SL[i] is the string that matched  
end;
```

Both `AnsiContainsText` and `AnsiCompareStr` can be found in the `StrUtils` unit.

Comment: Aha, that works perfectly! Just add StrUtils to uses :)

Comment: @Deathglider1: I should have mentioned that; I've added it to my answer for future readers. Thanks. :-)